# How to get specific string from a file and store it in new file in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I have one `sql` file that contain some data in this file some line as follow:

```
INSERT a=1 , b=2;  
INSERT a=2 , b=10;
```

like that so many lines are there i want to fetch these lines that contain "INSERT" keyword till semicolon and create a new file and save it into the new file.

using shell script.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -n '/^\s*INSERT/p' data > newfilename
$ cat newfilename 
INSERT a=1 , b=2;
INSERT a=2 , b=10;
```

or using `grep`:

```
$ grep '^INSERT' data > newfilename 
$ cat newfilename 
INSERT a=1 , b=2;
INSERT a=2 , b=10;
```

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk '/^INSERT/' data > newfilename
$ cat newfilename 
INSERT a=1 , b=2;
INSERT a=2 , b=10;
```

Comment: Thank you it is useful for me.

Comment: @anika welcome  .. kindly click on the tick mark on the left side of the answer and get the question solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
cat test.sql 
insert a = 1; b= 2;
delete a, b;
insert d = 8;
insert g = 9;

grep 'insert' test.sql > newfile
cat newfile 
insert a = 1; b= 2;
insert d = 8;
insert g = 9;
```

This will also help you

^ (caret)
means "the beginning of the line". So "^a" means find a line starting with an "a".

$ (dollar sign)
means "the end of the line". So "a$" means find a line ending with an "a".

For example, this command searches the file myfile for lines starting with an "s" and ending with an "n", and prints them to the standard output (screen):

cat myfile | grep '^s.*n$'